# Interrupt execution of a method in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing an objective C program. Below I have included a method that I'm running after clicking on a button in that program. Also there is a stop button in that program and when someone clicks on the stop button I wanna stop execution of this method and bring the UI of the application back to it's normal state which was before running the method. Can anyone help me to do this?

```
-(JobStatus)beginUploadingTask{

void (^progressBlock)(void);
progressBlock = ^{       
    @try{      
        do {

            // calls to some method

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //execute some code

                 });

        } while (index<fileSize);        
    }
    @catch (NSException *ex) {
        [self taskErrorWithMessage:@"Error in uploading your file. Please try again"];
        return;
    }
    @finally {

        NSLog(@ "finally block executed");
    }   
};
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, progressBlock);

return TaskStateUploaded;
```

}

Comment: to my knowledge, you can't stop a block on a queue, so maybe have a flag that is set on the main thread when the button is pressed that the block checks?

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C. Can u please explain that more?

Comment: ok, so this is a total guess.. at the top of your .m you'd have your flag, e.g. `static BOOL shouldQuitLoop = NO;`, then in your class you have a button action: `- (IBAction)quitButtonPressed:(id)sender { shouldQuitLoop = YES; }`. and finally in your block you have `@try { do { if (shouldQuitLoop) break; ........`. i haven't tried that myself, so it may not work :)